# Rails: get belongs_to class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to

I have a base class `Entry`, with lots of different subclasses. Such as:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
end

class UserEntry < Entry
    belongs_to :target, class_name: User
end
```

Is there a way to retrieve the `class_name` of the `target` association of the UserEntry class? It should return `User`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found what I'm looking for: [ActiveRecord::Reflection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html) class methods (the previous answers are helpful, but don't really answer the question)

I used the `reflect_on_association` class method to get the details of my `:target` association. So to get what I was looking for, I did:

`UserEntry.reflect_on_association(:target).klass`, which returned the `User` class.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the right thing, except `class_name` should be a `String`, not `Class`

`class UserEntry < Entry
    belongs_to :target, class_name: 'User'
end`

Comment: Does not have to be a string

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the `primary_key` and `foreign_key`  in the `belongs_to` because the AR is not smart enough to map `user_id` into `target_id`